# Cannot truncate a referenced table

Tags: sql-server, truncate

Currently I am working on a db project and I am regularly updating the database. My problem is that I cannot truncate table even though no table is referencing it. That is let we assume that table y and table z depends on a field in table x. I can truncate table y and table z but cannot truncate table x even though table y and table z are empty. I am using SQL Server. Can you please let me understand why this is happening and provide a solution? Thanks. (I googled but could not find a solution. )

Edit:
Let me also state that even though I emptied table x (using delete from table x) I can still not truncate it.

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: @esperento57 Error message is 'Cannot truncate table 'x' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.'

Comment: Actually database administrators can use foreign keys as a protection for Truncate Table command against data losses: http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/prevent-truncate-table-on-sql-server-database-using-foreign-key-constraint.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is by design.

If you want to truncate the table then

1. First you need to drop the `foreign key` constraints referencing your
   truncate table
2. Run `truncate` command
3. Recreate the `foreign key` constraints

Comment: what is the logic behind this @prdp? Even though all tables are empty why cannot I truncate the tables?

Comment: @tempx - Truncate is a `DDL` command unlike `delete` it cannot validate the data present in child tables. This is how am educated ;) some other reason could be there

Comment: if you use "delete from" and not "truncate" ?

Comment: @Prdp i can understand data validation. However, child table is empty, parent table is empty but I can not truncate parent table! How come? Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Esperento57 yes I can delete data from tables but cannot  truncate!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it as below

```
    DELETE FROM TableName
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (TableName, RESEED, 0)
```